# How to capitalize first letter of edit text in android

Tags: android

I tried following things still not working:

```
 android:inputType="textCapSentences"
 android:capitalize="sentences"
```

Comment: android:inputType="textCapSentences" is the right way to go about it. You might want to check for something which prevents this from working.

Comment: try removing `android:capitalize="sentences"`

Comment: removed  android:capitalize="sentences" but still facing same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these solution:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {            

    }
        @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {             
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable et) {
          String s=et.toString();
      if((!s.equals(s.toUpperCase()) && s.length()==1)) {
         s=s.toUpperCase();
         edittext.setText(s);
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: this solves first capital letter of the word,but how to add space and capital letter after dot (.)

Comment: Can you please give the string example..By which i can get easily that what you want to do..

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `inputType` attribute of the `EditText`. Try setting it to `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES`